# asp.net core 3.1 Razor Pages loading image as a byte[] to View

Tags: image, asp.net-core, razor-pages, abp

I would love some help in this as I have spent far too long on it.

I have to save many small files on an intranet app.
I am taking my image in as a type=file

```
  <abp-input asp-for="Storage.File" type ="file" />
```

Passing it to an IForm

```
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
```

Converting it in OnPostAsync to a byte[] and saving it.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //turn it into a memory stream file is an IFormFile
            await Storage.File.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            //pass the byte[] to Content
            Storage.Content = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

Then at the other end I am extracting it as a Stream, converting it to a form file and passing it across as an IFormFile using this great [SO post - How to deal with input=file / IFormFile two-way binding in Razor Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910091/how-to-deal-with-input-file-iformfile-two-way-binding-in-razor-pages)

```
        string imgType = "data:" + GetMimeTypes(Storage) + ";base64,";
        string filename = Storage.Name + Storage.ImageExt;

        var input = Storage.Content;
        using var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(input);
        var formFile = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, Storage.Name, Storage.Name);

        formFile.Headers = new HeaderDictionary()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>("Content-Disposition", $"form-data; name=\"{Storage.Name}\"; filename=\"{filename}\""),//"form-data; name=\"chicken\"; filename=\"chicken.png\""
                new KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>("Content-Type", imgType ),// "data:image/png;base64,"
            };
        Storage.Image = formFile;
```

To here I get data[image]

Then I am passing it to an IFormFile

```
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [FromForm(Name = "Image")]
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
```

And finally out in  a number of failed structures to the Razor page

```
        2<img src="Storage.Image" />
```

Sadly this is where I end, with no image and nothing in the src.

I have tried similar of `<img src="Storage.Image" />` and even  `<abp-input asp-for="Storage.Image" type ="image"/>`. sadly with no success.

All the data is passed in with the structure of class.property such as  `<abp-input asp-for="Storage.Name"/>`
Thanks So much

Comment: please try <img src="@Model.Storage.Image" />

Comment: Thanks, I have tried similar of <img src="Storage.Image" /> and even  <abp-input asp-for="Storage.Image" type ="image"/>. sadly with no success. All the data is passed in with the structure of class.property such as  <abp-input asp-for="Storage.Name"/>

Comment: src is not a Tag Helper, if you want to render image then you need to use @ in your src property of img tag.  <img src="@Model.Storage.Image" />  asp-for is a tag helper but it will not set the src property. you can also inspect  the element in chrome

Comment: Thanks NAS! I just thought it was the old MVC structure, But thats passing just an image across (which is a success in itself )  Any ideas how to get the Formfile to show as an image?